# Create file and folder from a text

Tags: powershell

I have a question about how to create files from a text
for example, I have `$source = "C:\folder1\folder11\file1.txt"` and destination is `$destination = "C:\folder2\folder22\file2.txt"`
the file and folders of the destination doesn't exist already.

I use this command powershell:

```
$source = "C:\folder1\folder11\file1.txt"
$destination = "C:\folder2\folder22\file2.txt"

Copy-Item $source -Destination  (New-Item -ItemType File -Path $destination -Force) -Force
```

this command creates the file: `file2.txt` and folder: `C:\folder2\folder22\` but with error:

> could not find a part of the path

do you have any idea how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -recurse switch will create the destination folder hierarchy if the source is a directory.

When the source is a file, `Copy-Item` expects the destination to be a file or directory that already exists.

So, do something like this:

```
$source = "C:\folder\String.txt"
$destination = "C:\folder2\folder22\file2.txt"

if(!(Test-Path $destination))
{
New-Item (Split-Path -Path $destination) -ItemType Directory -Force
}
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Force
```